# ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework, getting Id of latest added item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

With given repository interface:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    void Add(T entity);
    void Save();
}
```

And let's say concrete repository:

```
public ConcreteRepository : IRepository<Something>
{
    void Add(Something entity)
    {
        _context.Somethings.Add(entity);
    }
    void Save()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I have to get `Id` of latest item inserted into database. I need that, because in my app after user has posted form I would like to redirect him to newly created item.

My first thought was to just simply return `entity.Id` from `Add(T entity)` method, but I realized it's not possible, because I can get `Id` only after `SaveChanges()` which happens in another method.

I think this makes no sense to call `SaveChanges()` in my `Add()` method because in real life example repository contains more methods, for example `Edit()`, and then some of my methods would call `Save()` by themselves while other not? Doesn't sound like an good idea for me.

What would be an elegant way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 0):

Okay much easier than I thought if using Entity Framework 6.  Entity Framework will just update your original object with the Id once it has been committed to the database.

Example Model

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime Registered { get; set; }
}
```

Example Call of the Repository

```
public AddSomethingToDatabase()
{
    User user = new User
        {
            Email = "anotheruser@gmail.com",
            Registered = DateTime.UtcNow
        };

  _repository.Add(obj);
  _repository.Save();

  int id = obj.Id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it greatly depends on how is your entity Id is represented.
If your ids are simple sequentialy increasing integers, getting the latest item inserted into column is as simple as the following linq query:

```
var latestId = _.context.Somethings.Where(x => x.user == userId).Max(x => x.Id);
```

If your ids are Guids or some kind of custom strings, things are getting more complicated and it may be most comfortable to add boolean flag to each entity, marking whether it is latest or not.